# What method can I use to fetch data from nextjs api on page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webapi

I'm developing blog website with NextJS. I'm using directory app/api to create different endpoints which communicate with mongo database. Now I want to fetch data from these endpoints to display it on page. What method can I use to fetch data server or client side? Is it normal to use react query for fetching and have almost whole page as "use client"? Can I use "use server" functions to fetch data from endpoints? I know that I can use server actions, but I would like to have my website and web api separate. Or should I move to server actions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), the universal built-in fetching mechanism? (supported by all browsers as well as Node 18, the current LTS, and above)

Comment: If you're talking about your web api, you can use whatever you want.  So long as it has access to a database and you have the ability to change and secure the API with `CORS` settings .. The world is your oyster ..  IF you're talking only about retrieving FROM the endpoint .. You can do as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans states .and just use `fetch` --  You can also use `Axios` in next.js -- Makes things a little simpler for complicated setups IMO.

Comment: Right now I'm using `axios` to fetch data but in comparison to ssr it take about 1-3 second to load data, is it ok? I just started learing nextjs and I saw a lot of videos about servers side rendering and server actions, how it increases performance. It is my own web api, it is located in nextjs/app/api directory. and I have the same domain so cors are not needed

Comment: 1-3 seconds -- Well depending on the amount of data you are crunching/grabbing, and honestly the speed of your host, routing, mitigation and output ..  You can test the speed of your API directly by just hitting the URL in your browser, and creating a test endpoint with `GET`.  To give you a point of reference, for one project of mine, the API makes large SQL calls that return a 8MB+ JSON (50,000 rows) return and it does it between 2-3s on avg.  So for a large call I'd say yes that's acceptable.  For simple calls you should be < 1s

Comment: Ok , I got it, thank you! I checked it and if I open api url in browser, it loads almost instantly, but when I'm fetching the same api with react it takes some time